# Unzip nested jar files java

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to unzip all the jar files and the jar files which is nested in jar file.
For example, let's say there's a Test.jar and inside of the Test.jar, there is Test1.jar,,
What I tried to do is that making a temp directory and unzip them, when it was jar file, recursive call.

Here below is my code and the log I got. I have no idea on that.
I am pretty sure that the input was directory. I have no idea on resolving this error. Also, I am pretty sure that the error is from here (`Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, null, recursive);`)

```
Curr directory:/Users/younghoonkwon/jar-analyzer
unzipping directory/Users/younghoonkwon/jar-analyzer/test1.jar@
Curr directory:/Users/younghoonkwon/jar-analyzer/test1.jar@
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.validateListFilesParameters(FileUtils.java:545)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:521)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:691)
    at org.vulnerability.checker.JarParser.unzipJars(JarParser.java:31)
    at org.vulnerability.checker.JarParser.unzipJars(JarParser.java:38)
    at org.vulnerability.checker.VulnerabilityChecker.main(VulnerabilityChecker.java:26)
[/Users/younghoonkwon/jar-analyzer/test1.jar]
```

My code:

```
public void unzipJars(String toFind, String currDirectory) {
    File root = new File(currDirectory);
    try {
        boolean recursive = true;
        System.out.println("Curr directory:"+root);
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, null, recursive);
        for (Iterator<File> iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            File file = (File) iterator.next();
            if (file.getName().endsWith(toFind)) {
                if(toFind.endsWith("jar")) {
                    unzip(file.getAbsolutePath() + "@",file.getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("unzipping directory"+ file.getAbsolutePath()+"@");
                    unzipJars("jar", file.getAbsolutePath()+"@");
                    this.jarList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void unzip(String destDirPath, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("unzip "+ zipFilePath + " -d" + destDirPath);
}
```

Comment: The exception cause (`JarParser.findPath()`) and the posted source code appear unrelated.

Comment: Aww sorry edited.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm seems ok to me. The error seems to be caused by that the unzipped file is not a directory (but a file) or it does not exist. Your `unzip()` method does not throw any exeption if unzipping the .jar fails because of output file already existing.

Have you been running the code earlier which may have caused that the .jars or directories contain unwanted output files with the same name?

Before the call to `FileUtils.listFiles()`, check if the root `File` object is actually a directory and it exists (or if it's a file but not a directory) by [File.isDirectory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) or [File.isFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()).

Answer (score 0):

The following method `decompress()` unzips a JAR file and all the JAR files within it (recursively).

```java
  /**
   * Size of the buffer to read/write data.
   */
  private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 16384;

  /**
   * Decompress all JAR files located in a given directory.
   *
   * @param outputDirectory Path to the directory where the decompressed JAR files are located.
   */
  public static void decompress(final String outputDirectory) {
    File files = new File(outputDirectory);
    for (File f : Objects.requireNonNull(files.listFiles())) {
      if (f.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
        try {
          JarUtils.decompressDependencyFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());
          // delete the original dependency jar file
          org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          log.warn("Problem decompressing jar file: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Decompress all JAR files (recursively).
   *
   * @param zipFile The file to be decompressed.
   */
  private static void decompressDependencyFiles(String zipFile) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(zipFile);
    try (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file)) {
      String newPath = zipFile.substring(0, zipFile.length() - 4);
      new File(newPath).mkdir();
      Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipFileEntries = zip.entries();
      // Process each entry
      while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
        // grab a zip file entry
        ZipEntry entry = zipFileEntries.nextElement();
        String currentEntry = entry.getName();
        File destFile = new File(newPath, currentEntry);
        File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();
        // create the parent directory structure if needed
        destinationParent.mkdirs();
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
          BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(zip.getInputStream(entry));
          int currentByte;
          // establish buffer for writing file
          byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
          // write the current file to disk
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
          try (BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER_SIZE)) {
            // read and write until last byte is encountered
            while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
              dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
            }
            dest.flush();
            is.close();
          }
        }
        if (currentEntry.endsWith(".jar")) {
          // found a zip file, try to open
          decompressDependencyFiles(destFile.getAbsolutePath());
          FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(destFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```